# Nspire CAS spitting out a wrong answer?

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the integral:
$$\int \frac{8x+11}{(2x+3)(x+1)}$$
My Nspire CAS tells me that the answer to this is 
$$\ln\left\lvert(x+1)^3 \cdot (2x+3)\right\lvert$$

This is not the correct answer according to my calculations and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%288x%2B11%29%2F%28%282x%2B3%29%28x%2B1%29%29)

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Absolute value is ridiculous in LaTeX. It's \lvert *expression* \rvert. Of course, you could do any number of things, but purists always prefer this method.

Comment: Wolfram alpha tells you the same - if you check the footer, it defines log as the natural logarithm, i.e. ln. (Still a funny way to write it)
Then: 3log(x+1) + log(2x+3) = log((x+1)^3) + log(2x+3) = log((x+1)^3(2x+3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

Using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)

$$\frac{8x+11}{(2x+3)(x+1)}=\frac A{2x+3}+\frac B{x+1}$$

Do you know $\displaystyle \ln a+\ln b=\ln ab$ and consequently $\displaystyle c\cdot\ln a=\ln (a^c)$ (assuming if each logarithm is defined) ?

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you.

Comment: Hear, hear! Calculators, boo!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is correct.

$$\log ((x+1)^3 (2x+3)) = 3\log(x+1) + \log(2x+3)$$

Comment: Whoops. Looks like I was too quick to post this time. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like WolframAlpha agrees with the answer from NSpire.

Are you *sure* they disagree?